# Ambiguous Source ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I tried to make an alias because it exits as an item in both tables I'm trying to join, but I keep getting an ambiguous error for sourceId.

```
SELECT isAccepted, sourceId,
FROM `nyt-bigquery-beta-workspace.comments_data.comments_backend` as cb
  LEFT JOIN dig_pubp.content_master_filtered as cm
  ON(REPLACE(cb.articleId, 'article_', '') = cb.sourceId)
```

Comment: Use aliases in front of all column names. You've missed them in the select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT cb.isAccepted, cb.sourceId,
FROM `nyt-bigquery-beta-workspace.comments_data.comments_backend` cb
  LEFT JOIN dig_pubp.content_master_filtered cm
  ON(REPLACE(cb.articleId, 'article_', '') = cb.sourceId)
```

change the alias for select depending on which table it is in

Also are you purposely joining on columns from the same table? Or should one of those identifiers be 'cm'

Comment: Good flag - one should be cm. However, I'm now getting another error: "BigQuery error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

Comment: no worries! if this solved your issue accepting the answer will mark it as closed. Happy coding!

Comment: @fthomson . . . This doesn't answer the question in BQ because the query does not work in that database.

Comment: I would have changed one of the aliases in the join, but I didn't know which tables each of the columns were in. Are there any other issues with the query? As far as I can tell the error in the comments was from switching to an outer join.